# Find which model method is triggering the Event

Tags: laravel, laravel-events, laravel-models

I'm using Laravel's Event & Listener functionality to detect the following model actions and trigger some application logic.

app/models/MealFood

```
/**
 * The event map for the model.
 *
 * Allows for object-based events for native Eloquent events.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'created'  => MealFoodEvent::class,
    'updated'  => MealFoodEvent::class,
    'deleted'  => MealFoodEvent::class
];
```

app/events/MealFoodEvent

```
public $mealFood;

/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @param MealFood $mealFood
 */
public function __construct(MealFood $mealFood)
{
    $this->mealFood = $mealFood;
}
```

app/listeners/MealFoodListener

```
public function handle(MealFoodEvent $event)
{
    $mealFood = $event->mealFood;
}
```

Is it possible to detect what model action triggered the event? I want to be able to know if the record triggering the event was created/updated/deleted. Right know I'm using soft deletes to check if the record was deleted but how can I know if the record was updated or created?

Comment: Why don't you create 3 classes? They could all inherit from `MealFood` and you could then determine which event was fired by checking which class is running.

Comment: not sure I understand. 3 classes for what? extending the model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create 3 additional classes:

MealFoodCreatedEvent.php

```
class MealFoodCreatedEvent extends MealFoodEvent {}
```

MealFoodUpdatedEvent.php

```
class MealFoodUpdatedEvent extends MealFoodEvent {}
```

MealFoodDeletedEvent.php

```
class MealFoodDeletedEvent extends MealFoodEvent {}
```

Modify your model:

```
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'created'  => MealFoodCreatedEvent::class,
    'updated'  => MealFoodUpdatedEvent::class,
    'deleted'  => MealFoodDeletedEvent::class
];
```

Then in your event handler you can just do:

```
public function handle(MealFoodEvent $event)
{
    $mealFood = $event->mealFood;
    if ($event instanceof MealFoodCreatedEvent) { 
       // the event was "created
    }
}
```

The signature for `handle` still works because all your events extend `MealFoodEvent`

You can also make `MealFoodEvent` abstract since you will never need to create an instance of it directly.